# Use of htmlFor in Formik - React

Tags: reactjs, formik

I guess there is no clear context for this anywhere. Can someone explain what is the use for `htmlFor` in [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/overview)?

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
  <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" onChange={formik.handleChange} value={formik.values.title} />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-react-zs336?file=/src/App.js:424-877).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Formik, it's a regular HTML attribute for labels, indicating which element it is a label for: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_label_htmlfor.asp

Comment: 'htmlFor' is used in JSX which is same as 'for' in HTML, used for accessibility.

Answer (score 4):

The prop 'htmlFor' in JSX is the same as attribute 'for' in HTML. It is used for labels to link them with their inputs (using input id). So that when clicking on this label is the same as clicking on the input. It is especially helpful for checkboxes and radio buttons. Simple inputs also get focused when a linked label is clicked.
Another way to link label and input is to set the input as a child of label `<label><input/></label>`.

Comment: It should be noted that this is common to all JSX (such as React), not just Formik. The reason for `htmlFor` rather than `for` is that `for` is a reserved word in JavaScript.